# Please help me to fix formula to use IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS functions

Tags: excel

I am trying to use `IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS` functions together with out any luck. Below is the formula that I am trying to use. Please note that individual `INDIRECT(ADDRESS` function work well and I can also use them in `SUM` function but I am not able to use it with `IF` or `IF(AND` functions.

```
IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN()))>=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4)),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN()))<=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),5)))INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN())))

IF(AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN()))>=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),4)),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN()))<=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),5)))INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,COLUMN())))
```

Comment: Which of your two examples works? Which one does not?

Comment: Looks like each of those is missing a comma. INDEX would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INDEX is preferred to INDIRECT(ADDRESS)) if for nothing else but lower calculation lag when unassociated values are changed.

```
'indirect/address
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3, COLUMN()))
'index
INDEX(3:3, 1, COLUMN())
```

Two INDEX function pair up nicely for a true range.

```
'with this in D10 it references SUM(D3:D9)
=SUM(INDEX(3:3, 1, COLUMN()):INDEX(9:9, 1, COLUMN()))
```

An example for IF(AND(...

```
'with this in A1 it references IF(AND(A3>=D1, A3<=E1), A3)
=IF(AND(INDEX(3:3, 1, COLUMN())>=INDEX(D:D, ROW(), 1)),
        INDEX(3:3, 1, COLUMN())<=INDEX(E:E, ROW(), 1))),
    INDEX(3:3, 1, COLUMN()))
```

Be careful that you aren't creating circular referenced formulas with these sculpted cell references.